# Can't get cubes to move the way I want

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm working on a OpenGL ES app for Android that's supposed to spawn a cube that shoots cubes toward the section of the screen that the user touches. However, whenever I spawn "child" cubes, the main cube starts moving and the child cubes don't even show up.

The cubes are represented by the Cube class. This is inherited by ChildCube (which in turn is inherited by SmallChildCube) and MainCube. Cube stores its position in three floats (x, y, z). The update() method then uses these values to calculate the transformation matrix:

```
public void update() {
    long passedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - lastTime;

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);

    // rotate the cube
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(movementAngle), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // translation
    pos.x += passedTime/1000.0d * (double)movementSpeed * Math.sin(movementAngle);
    pos.y += passedTime/1000.0d * (double)movementSpeed * Math.cos(movementAngle);
    pos.z += passedTime/1000.0d * (double)movementSpeed * 0.0d;
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

    lastTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
}
```

All user input is handled in my CubeRenderer class (which inherits GLSurfaceView.Renderer). The input is passed on from the activity to this class, and is handled like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Vec2 cubePos = mainCube.getPositionOnScreen();

            int mainCubePixelX = (int)(cubePos.x * width);
            int mainCubePixelY = (int)(cubePos.y * height);

            Vec2 pressedCoordinates = new Vec2(e.getX(), e.getY());

            // calculate the angle using the center of the cube (0 degrees is upwards)
            double angle = Math.atan2(cubePixelX - pressedCoordinates.x, cubePixelY - pressedCoordinates.y);

            // spawn child cubes
            childCubes.add(new SmallChildCube(mainCube.getPos()));
            childCubes.lastElement().setMovementAngle(angle);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And finally the updating which takes place in my CubeRenderer.onDrawFrame():

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // view matrix
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // multiply the matrices
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // update everything
        mainCube.update();
        if(childCubes.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCubes.size(); i++) {
                childCubes.elementAt(i).update();
            }
        }

        // render everything
        mainCube.draw(mViewProjectionMatrix);
        if(qubieBullets.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCubes.size(); i++) {
                childCubes.elementAt(i).draw(mViewProjectionMatrix);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if I click on a part of the screen, the main cube starts moving towards (and past) it even though its movementSpeed is declared as 0.0f in the constructor. However, if I comment out the line that updates every child cube within the childCubes vector, the main cube stays where it's supposed to.

Does anyone understand why the main cube is moving, and the spawned child cubes don't show up? If necessary, I'll upload the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, how silly of me!

When I handled the input and created a new child cube

```
childCubes.add(new SmallChildCube(mainCube.getPos()));
```

I didn't copy the values from mainCube's position into a new Vec3 as I thought I did. Instead, the line above simply tells the objects to use the same Vec3.

New functioning code:

```
Vec3 mainCubePos = mainCube.getPos();
childCubes.add(new SmallChildCube(new Vec3(mainCubePos.x, mainCubePos.y, mainCubePos.z));
```